# Create a specific work item (Bug) for test case in Azure DevOps pipelines--Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, yaml

I'm using Azure DevOps to run test cases using Selenium.

I want to know how to create a work item when a test case fail in selenium

The pipeline is completing without error( without notifying that the test case has failed)

Below is the code from my yml pipeline:

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- master


pool: 'Self hosted agent'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8.0_231'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: 'Logs/*'
    goals: 'package'
- task: BatchScript@1
  inputs:
    filename: 'merge.bat'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with azure devops. You most likely did not set your maven project correctly. You need to double check your pom.xml and testing.xml to make sure the plugins and dependencies etc. are configured correctly.

I have a maven project for testing purpose. The pipeline fails when my testcases failed. And the test result was published to the **Tests** tab of the pipeline summary page.

> Below is part of my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependency libraries to include for compilation -->
               <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>

        </dependency>  

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                   </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling
                the code -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
   </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

> My azure-pipelines.yml

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'mymavenproject/pom.xml'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```

When I ran my pipeline, it failed as expected.

[image]

As I set `publishJUnitResults: true` in my maven tasks. The test results is published to the **Tests** tab. You can then view your test results in the Tests tab.

> You can create workitem bugs for each failed testcases by click the **Bug** in the Tests results page. Please refer to below screenshot.

[image]